# Get Sales Commoditywise in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to present commodity wise sales for the year. But all commodities should be shown but the sales is presented for those commodities which are belonged the particular year and the remaining commodities just presented with null values but the year should be the selected year.

I have below data.

```
Declare @table table (Commodity Varchar(10),Sales int,YearOfSale INT)
INSERT INTO @Table
Values('Samsung',300,2020)
,('OPPO',500,2020)
,('NOKIA',700,2020)
,('OPPO',1000,2020)
,('REDMI',100,2029)
,('KORBON',90,2019)
```

I want the below result.

```
Commodity   TOTALSALES  YearOfSale
----------------------------------
OPPO            1500    2020
NOKIA           700     2020
Samsung         300     2020
REDMI           NULL    2020
KORBON          NULL    2020
```

I have tried the below

```
;WITH Commodity
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Commodity
        ,YearOfSale
    FROM @Table
    )
    ,Sales
AS (
    SELECT Commodity
        ,SUM(Sales) Sales
        ,YearOfSale
    FROM @Table
    WHERE YearOfsale=2020
    GROUP BY Commodity
        ,YEAROfsale
    )
SELECT P.Commodity
    ,CASE 
                WHEN Sales IS NOT NULL
                    THEN Sales 
                END TOTALSALES
    ,P.YearOfSale
FROM Commodity P
LEFT JOIN Sales QS ON P.Commodity = QS.Commodity
ORDER BY Sales DESC
```

I am getting year 2019 but I need to present 2020.
I would really appreciate a bit of help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in the 2020 sales, you can just hardcode it in the result column. And you don't need the `YearOfSale` in the `Commodity` cte

```
;WITH Commodity
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Commodity
    FROM @Table
    )
    ,Sales
AS (
    SELECT Commodity
        ,SUM(Sales) Sales
        ,YearOfSale
    FROM @Table
    WHERE YearOfSale=2020
    GROUP BY Commodity
        ,YearOfSale
    )
SELECT P.Commodity
    ,Sales
    ,YearOfSale = 2020
FROM Commodity P
LEFT JOIN Sales QS ON P.Commodity = QS.Commodity
ORDER BY Sales DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern here is to `CROSS JOIN` the Years and Commodities to create a rows for every combination and then `LEFT JOIN` the sales to fill in the sales for the (Commodity,Year) pairs that have any actual sales.  EG

```
SELECT P.Commodity, Y.YearOfSale, Sum(S.Sales) TotalSales
FROM Commodity P
CROSS JOIN Years Y
LEFT JOIN @table  S 
  ON P.Commodity = S.Commodity
 AND Y.YearOfSale = S.YearOfSale 
GROUP BY P.Commodity, Y.YearOfSale
ORDER BY TotalSales DESC
```

Note that you may need to create lookup tables for the years and the commodities if you don't already have these.  Or you could derive these from your sales table, eg

```
Declare @table table (Commodity Varchar(10),Sales int,YearOfSale INT)
INSERT INTO @Table
Values('Samsung',300,2020)
,('OPPO',500,2020)
,('NOKIA',700,2020)
,('OPPO',1000,2020)
,('REDMI',100,2029)
,('KORBON',90,2019);


with 
  Commodity as (select distinct Commodity from @table),
  Years as (select distinct YearOfSale from @table)
SELECT P.Commodity, Y.YearOfSale, Sum(S.Sales) TotalSales
FROM Commodity P
CROSS JOIN Years Y
LEFT JOIN @table  S 
  ON P.Commodity = S.Commodity
 AND Y.YearOfSale = S.YearOfSale 
GROUP BY P.Commodity, Y.YearOfSale
ORDER BY TotalSales DESC
```

outputs

```
Commodity  YearOfSale  TotalSales
---------- ----------- -----------
OPPO       2020        1500
NOKIA      2020        700
Samsung    2020        300
REDMI      2029        100
KORBON     2019        90
NOKIA      2019        NULL
OPPO       2019        NULL
REDMI      2019        NULL
Samsung    2019        NULL
KORBON     2020        NULL
KORBON     2029        NULL
NOKIA      2029        NULL
OPPO       2029        NULL
Samsung    2029        NULL
REDMI      2020        NULL
```